# Replacing Logic operator List and generate combination of variables

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, conditional, inequalities

so I'm trying to do the following starting from a list of inequalities:

```
In={{a>b&&b<c&&c<1},{a<b&&b<c&&d<c&&d<1}}
```

I want to do the following:

convert the list of inequalities into a list of list

```
InL={{a>b,b<c,c<1},{a<b,b<c,d<c,d<1}}
```

given some of the variable in the inequalities separate them form the others (ex c,d)

```
InLS={{{a>b},{b<c,c<1}},{{a<b},{b<c,d<c,d<1}}}
```

Could someone please help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: Mathematica has powerful logic and boolean functions. Be sure to check them out before embarking in a reinvent-the-wheel enterprise http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LogicAndBooleanAlgebra.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
in = {{a > b && b < c && c < 1}, {a < b && b < c && d < c && d < 1}};

in /. And -> (Sequence @@ GatherBy[{##}, FreeQ[c | d]] &)
```

> ```
> {{{a > b}, {b < c, c < 1}}, {{a < b}, {b < c, d < c, d < 1}}}
> ```

The code above uses the v10 operator form for `FreeQ`; if you are using an earlier version replace `FreeQ[c | d]` with `FreeQ[#, c | d] &`.

Comment: @Yyrkoon You're welcome.  Let me know if you need any part of this explained.